# stack.pop() inside of if statement

Tags: java, stack, lifo

I am wondering if calling the `pop()` method from the `Stack` data structure within an if statement will pop off the first element from the stack?

Here is an example of code:

```
public void pop() {
    if(stack.pop() == min) min=stack.pop();
}
```

Will this work? Or is it better to declare it like so:

```
public void pop() {
    int poppedOff = stack.pop();
    if(poppedOff == min) min=stack.pop();
}
```

I am assuming these are doing the same things but I am not completely sure.

Comment: Unless you can prove that when `min` is at the top of the stack there will ***always*** be another element on the stack, you run the risk of throwing an `EmptyStackException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It will, every invocation of `pop` will pop an element off the stack. Use `peek()` or save the value when you call `pop()` (like your second example). Also, setting `min` to the value when it equals the value is pointless.

Comment: It's setting it to the *next* element.